# Cannot install Ruby 1.9.3 on Mountain Lion w/ Jewlery Box: Error running make -j4 (have current readline, gcc)

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to install Ruby 1.9.3 on my Mountain Lion equipped MBP using Jewelery Box (can use terminal, though). Every time I compile the install, I get the error: "Error running make -j4" and Jewelry Box aborts. I have the current versions of XCode, Readline, and gcc, and yes, I have tried compiling with Clang :)

Here is my log:

http://pastebin.com/FVLsxZ6P

The errors in question (if you don't want to click on the link) are, assumedly:

```
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa      0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib for architecture x86_64
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib for architecture x86_64
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa  0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [../../../.ext/x86_64-darwin12.0.0/digest/md5.bundle] Error 1
make[2]: *** [../../../.ext/x86_64-darwin12.0.0/digest/sha2.bundle] Error 1
make[2]: make[1]: *** [../../../.ext/x86_64-darwin12.0.0/digest/sha1.bundle] Error 1*** [ext/digest/md5/all] Error 2

make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [ext/digest/sha2/all] Error 2 
make[1]: *** [ext/digest/sha1/all] Error 2
installing default rmd160 libraries
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [../../../.ext/x86_64-darwin12.0.0/digest/rmd160.bundle] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/digest/rmd160/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Thanks for your help! Again, I HAVE GCC V 4.2.1, THE CURRENT VERSION OF READLINE, AND THE CURRENT VERSION OF XCODE.

Answer (score 0):

```
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format
```

Looks like your problem is with libz, not gcc/readline.   Update your libz lib.

Comment: How would i go about doing that? Also I laughed out loud when I read libz lib.