# Cannot install Ruby 1.9.3 on Mountain Lion w/ RVM: Error running make

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, osx-mountain-lion, libz

I'm trying to install Ruby so I can do the "Learn Ruby the Hard Way" course, and I've just been having tons of trouble installing the newest version of Ruby

Here's the relevant part of my log:

```
compiling md5ossl.c
linking shared-object digest/md5.bundle
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../../../.ext/x86_64-darwin12.1.0/digest/md5.bundle] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/digest/md5/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

I googled around and found this post looking like the exact same problem: [Cannot install Ruby 1.9.3 on Mountain Lion w/ Jewlery Box: Error running make -j4 (have current readline, gcc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765527/cannot-install-ruby-1-9-3-on-mountain-lion-w-jewlery-box-error-running-make-j)

But the answer there is an ambiguous "update libz lib". I don't know what that means, I googled around and found zlib but I don't know if these are the same thing as libz? I also found another post indicating libz is libtool, my libtool version is Apple Inc. version cctools-829, but is libtool the same thing as libz? I've never seen any of these terms before or used Ruby before and am just totally confused.

I have gcc 4.2.1 and xcode 4.4.1. Thanks for any help, this is my first post on here so please kindly let me know if I did anything incorrectly or need to provide more information. I basically stole my title from the title I linked to because I wasn't sure about how to format titles, I hope that's okay.

Comment: Yes, zlib and libz are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

As a note, OS X does not put anything in `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/local/bin` so you must've installed something there yourself, perhaps even inadvertently.

If you're using a Ruby manager like [rvm](http://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](http://rbenv.org/) then they have special build tools to help with this process. It's a lot easier than installing from source since the correct patches are applied not only to Ruby but the dependencies like `libz`.

What you might have is libraries compiled for the wrong architecture on your machine. These may have been rolled over from an old PowerPC install or even Intel 32-bit one from a version of OS X prior to 10.5.

Your best bet might be to simply remove `/usr/local/lib/libz*` and use the ones that come bundled with your OS instead. You should have a set of the required files in `/usr/lib/libz*` that can work.

Comment: You can also easily check what architecture it's compiled for by running the file command in a shell "file /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib"